# Hover на картинке

Tags: javascript, css

Есть картинка с прозрачным фоном. Как отрабатывать hover при наведении на саму картинку, а не на ее прозрачный фон?

Comment: Напишите пожалуйста примерный html код этой картинки и на что вы хотите влиять ховером

Comment: Исходный код не важен в данном вопросе. Есть картинка которую я добавил на страницу. Эта картинка на прозрачном фоне. Необходимо чтобы hover срабатывал только по наведению на картинку, а не на ее прозрачный фон.

Comment: <img class="test" src="test.png">

. test:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
картинка 100х100, изображение на ней 90х90, не нужно чтобы hover работал на прозрачный фон

Comment: Я вас понял. Вашим путём это невозможно реализовать, но есть кое-что, скоро отпишу.

Comment: Спасибо, знаю что не возможно реализовать в лоб. Появилась необходимость в этом, и я просто не знаю с какой стороны подойти к решению этой проблемы.

Comment: Все же вам необходимо привести код в вопросе. Потому что картинка может быть разной, от этого будет зависеть способ решения.

Comment: Вы можете задать новый вопрос, но не про то как сделать не кликабельным фон, а про свою задачу, что вам нужно решить в конечном итоге получив то что вы хотите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кому интересно. Чтобы найти изображение без прозрачного фона: 
1. Отрисуем картинку на холсте, и пробежимся по пикселям. проверяя каждый на прозрачность (data[3] - alpha). Находим контур картинки.
2. Найденые координаты добавляем в '< area>'
3. Теперь на '< area>' можем вашать всякое

Большое спасибо Nikita Shahov за то что направил в правильном направлении)

```
this.canvas = document.getElementById('.canvas');
this.ctxCanvas = this.canvas.getContext('2d');    


let image = new Image();
let mapActivity = [];
this.image.src = this.imgUrl;
this.image.onload = () => {
      this.ctxCanvas.drawImage(this.image, 0, 0, width, height);
      for (let x = 0; x <= height; x++) {
        for (let y = 0; y <= width; y++) {
          if (this.ctxCanvas.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data[3]) {
            this.mapActivity.push(x, y);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      for (let x = 0; height >= x; x++) {
        for (let y = width; y >= 0; y--) {
          if (this.ctxCanvas.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data[3]) {
            this.mapActivity.push(x, y);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

Изображения типа png имеют альфа канал, то есть они не обрезаны по контуру, они имеют такую же квадратную форму как и другие изображения, но там где нет изображения - есть 100% прозрачность(альфа-канал). 
А так же блок img имеет квадратную форму дефолтно подстраивающуюся под изображение.

Есть старые объекты, такие как area заключённые в тег map. Они имеют свободную кликабельную область, использовались для выделения например территорий городов на картах. Вы можете поверх изображения повесить area и уже на него повесить hover

Comment: Добавлю, что в 2018 уже можно использовать картинки без фона) Надеюсь в 2028 они будут доступны через css, а не только инлайновым свг)

Comment: Спасибо большое, не было возможности ранее отписаться) все получилось благодаря Вам, если интересно, ответ приложил =)